# As soon as I connect via VPN I lose internet access

Tags: vpn, internet, cisco-vpn

I am currently running Windows 7 32bit.  I have both the Cisco VPN client and the Shrew Soft VPN client, both work as expected.  The only problem is that I lose connection with the internet so I cannot browse Google, etc.

Comment: Are you the admin of the VPN or just the user?  If you're just a user this may be how the admin decided to set up the VPN.  But check your proxy settings and routing table.

Comment: Just the user.  I am going from an ADSL connection with a billion 7404VGO router.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is standard practice to route ALL of your traffic over a VPN connection while connected.

There is often a setting within the client to *only* send traffic destined for that particular network over the VPN connection, but this is called **split-tunelling**, and is considered a security risk.  The problem is that an attacker could gain access to your computer over your regular connection (virus/backdoor/etc), and they would now have access to your corporate network via the VPN - effectively bypassing any security your corporate network has put in place.

Answer (score 5):

The Cisco VPN Client has an option for "Split Tunneling".

This allows you to see your network and the connected VPN Network at the same time.

What sounds like is happening is when you connect to the VPN Host they do not have this option enabled, therefore you use their resources for everything. If you want to surf the web it would be off their connection, ISP, IP Addresses etc. If they have locked this down you would not be able to do so.

I had a similar problem where I could not see my network printer at home once I VPN'd in until split tunneling was enabled.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common configuration, as Home Boy and others have noted.

The best solution is to run your VPN session, and associated work, inside of a virtual machine (VMWare, Virtual Box, or whatever you choose) so that only that box's network is impacted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are becoming part of the corporate network (or whatever network you are connecting thru vpn) and you might have to use their proxy in ur browser to be able to browse.

Comment: either that or your routes are messed up and it is trying to send everything via the VPN which ain't working out too well for you.

Comment: Split tunneling isn't always allowed by the VPN.

Comment: That is correct.  I am connecting to a corporate network from an ADSL connection at home.

Comment: @3dinfluence.  Split tunneling is an option is it?

Comment: @Nathan Fisher: the spit tunneling policy is setup by the network admin in charge of the VPN endpoint. You can't control it on the client side. A lot of corporation do not enable split tunneling as a security measure.

Comment: Some VPN solutions also provide you an option to connect using browser, instead of a VPN stand-alone client application. In such a split tunnel is established on the browser session only and you could continue to connect to other sites, internet apps...

Answer (score 0):

run wireshark and listen on your nic. request a web page and see where the packets go.